# Color is lost after adding string format

Tags: android, colors, string-formatting, spannable

I need to add some text in a textview with some text with red color and some are black color with a specific formatting

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(temp.substring(start, i));
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, wordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
//failedToSolve.append(wordtoSpan); // was working when I used no formatting
failedToSolve.append(String.format("%7s", wordtoSpan)); // coloring is not working after I apply String.format on it
```

I know I am formatting `Spannable` object with `String` class method. Is there any alternatives? 
How can I do the formatting and coloring together? I used HTML tag but no effects. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any alternatives?

Call `String.format()` first, then create the `SpannableString` from the result and apply the `ForegroundColorSpan`.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply, Is there any difference between `SpannableString` and `Spannable` ?

Comment: @typedef: `Spannable` is an interface. `SpannableString` is an implementation of that interface.