# Not able to add color to the part of the text in a sentence for the below code

Tags: android, kotlin

Am not able to set color for a specific text in a sentence.

```
val wordtoSpan: Spannable = SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers")
wordtoSpan.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
itemView.webViewFeedContent.setAsWebView(wordtoSpan.toString(), mActivity)
```

Comment: `toString()` removes all formatting.

Comment: Okay, can you please say me the solution

Comment: He answered the same question 7 years ago, check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643660/color-is-lost-after-adding-string-format

Comment: Its not working

Comment: I do not know what `setAsWebView()` is doing, so I cannot give you a solution. In general, once you create a `Spannable` and apply styles to it, you need to keep it in its current form (or the `CharSequence` supertype). Do not call `toString()`. So, if `setAsWebView()` takes a `String` as its first parameter, you will need to fix `setAsWebView()`.